# Replace log10(0)-values in 2D plots with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting the profile of the energy for a 1D lattice as a 2D graph. The data are collected from snapshots that save the state of the lattice at a give time. The profile is highly localized with many zeros outside the active zone. This give the following profile [[fig]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FEZE.png).

I would like to fill the empty spaces (produced by the log10(0)) with the minimum of the `cbrange[..]` to fill that space with the coldest color.

Can someone help?

Here is the code I am using

```
set terminal pngcairo

n=1000  # Number of snapshots
mincb = -16; maxcb = -2
load 'color_dnls.pal'
set cbrange[mincb:maxcb]
unset key
set style fill solid
set ylabel "Snapshot/Time"
set xrange[0:2021]
set yrange[0:8]

snapshot(i) = sprintf("snapshot_%04d.dat", i)
set output 'norm_distr.png'

plot for [i=1:n] './snapshots/'. snapshot(n+1-i) using 1:(log10($2)):(log10($3)) with boxes linecolor palette,\
  'RV_0001.dat' using 10:(log10($1)) lc 'black' lw 3 lt 2 with lines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a simple check in the `using` part:

```
plot for [i=1:n] './snapshots/'. snapshot(n+1-i) using 1:(log10($2)):($3 > 0 ? log10($3) : mincb) with boxes linecolor palette
```